# Implement Change data capture in Apache Camel

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel

I am developing an  api using Apace Camel and Spring boot which sends starttime and endtime parameter to an endpoint and retrieves any new data changes between starttime and endtime duration. This api will be scheduled to run every hour and will pull data created in last one hour using starttime , endtime parameter.

Our requirement is store endtime of the previous execution so that in case of any application shutdown/maintenance, it stores the last execution run time and when application is again started , it can automatically picks up last run time and pull data from that timestamp.

Is there any way to store last execution timestamp in application.properties file and retrieve this value  on restart?

Comment: Its really weird to save end time in a property file. Just save it to a database and pick it up from there.

Comment: @karthik saving in a properties file is more effective than a database. Besides storing one value in a single table is really a waste of resource so file storage here makes sense. A database has overhead such as connections and maintenance and if you want to do is store a single date then a file is less work.

Comment: This is called a high water mark. You can just create a file on the file system somewhere and then write to this file. It does not have to be in the application.properties file. You could also look at a caching service like redis or infinispan but if you are only going to store one value then they might be overkill.

Comment: @Namphibian my thought was not to use a application.properties file. saving to a file or redis should be fine :)

Comment: @karthik yeah okay that makes sense. Perfectly fine. A properties file change might kick off a pod restart if you are running on K8s so yeah keep it in a separate file.